# Как переобразовать базу

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста, как из базы вида

Login: test

Password: 123123

Login: test1

Password: 123123

Login: test2

Password: 123123

Сделать

test:123123

test1:123123

test2:123123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант использовать регулярные выражения. К примеру, такой вариант:

```
import re

text = """Login: test1
Password: 123123
Login: test2
Password: 123123
Login: test3
Password: 123123"""

print(dict(re.findall('Login:\s*([\S]+)\s*Password:\s*([\S]+)', text)))
```

Поиск через re.findall, после чего пары преобразуются в словарь. Если пара не уникальная, как в Вашем примере, то в словаре будет одно уникальное значение. Я для примера поменял логины.